# How to not load font faces from desktop files?

Tags: fonts, desktop

I use `desktop-save` and `desktop-change-dir` a lot. Recently, I upgraded my hardware and now have a screen with way more DPI. This forced me to increase the font size in emacs.

Unfortunately, all my desktop files contain a font definition:

```
(setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (22300 50983 182648 566000) (desktop . "206") "horazont@sinistra.sotecware.net" nil nil ((((font-backend xft x) (font . "-unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-11-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1") (font-parameter) […]
```

Is there a way to make emacs ignore the font from desktop files, and ideally, not store it there at all?

I could hack up a sed-call to fix my desktop files, but I really would prefer emacs not to save the font at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to hook `desktop-after-read-hook` in `~/.emacs` to set the desired face after loading a desktop file.

```
(defun fix-face ()
  "fix the face after desktop-change-dir"
  (custom-set-faces
   '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 100 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "Hack")))))
  )
(add-hook 'desktop-after-read-hook 'fix-face)
```

This duplicates setting the face and is not found by `customize-variable`, so unfortunately it requires manual fiddling with the .emacs file whenever the default face has to be changed.